# Constructing a Pay to Download music website with wordpress

Tags: plugins, multisite, design, membership, paypal

Hi i searched the complete archive of wordpress plugins  but couldn't find the right plugin to enable Paid downloads. The website is just a Pay to download "Full Music" site. Visitor is provided with a sample music to hear and if he decides to download the music he should pay to dowload via Payment gateway like Paypal, Alertpay etc.
I would love to hear from your experiences and thoughts about this

Answer (score 1):

[eShop](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eshop/) and [wp e-commerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) both offer downloadable products.